# Netty 4.0.10 Channel auto read

Tags: java, netty

I am developing an app with the new netty framework. However when there is a new connected channel I disable the auto read until when I have done the necessary checks and setup by issuing the this.channel.config().setAutoRead(false);. When I have done all the checks I now set the autoread to true. I would like to know if by resetting it to  true will have the same effect like as it was in the default or I have to do what is said in the New and Note worthy doc.

The reason I am asking that question is that in the New and Note worthy doc it is stated that when I disable the autoread I have to be issuing read command in a event called channelReadSuspended()which I cannot even find.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Once you set it back to autoread it will behave again like the default. If this is not the case it's a bug.